# Understanding conda install debug messages

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

While installing `jupyter notebook` in an environment that I had previously created, I got the following debug messages.

The command I used was

```
>activate py2
>conda install jupyter notebook
```

Once the packages were downloaded, the prompt waited for a few minutes, before printing out:

```
DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(185): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl', env_name: 'crawl', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(299): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\\Users\\Uname\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\Users\\Uname\\Anaconda3\\envs\\crawl', 'C:\\Users\\Uname\\Anaconda3\\envs\\crawl\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Uname\\Anaconda3\\envs\\crawl\\Scripts\\jupyter-notebook-script.py', '%USERPROFILE%']
```

I don't know if something has gone wrong with the installation

Ok I also installed the `nb_conda` package and launched Jupyter notebook. I  get these error messages:

```
(crawl) c:\Users\Uname\Documents\python_scripts\notebooks>jupyter notebook
[E 10:33:12.086 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] couldn't call conda:
    [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[I 10:33:12.086 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 0 kernels found
[I 10:33:14.018 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 10:33:14.034 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 10:33:14.266 NotebookApp] \u2713 nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 10:33:14.266 NotebookApp] \u2717 nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named 'nbbrowserpdf'
[I 10:33:14.706 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: c:\Users\Uname\Documents\python_scripts\notebooks
[I 10:33:14.706 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 10:33:14.706 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 10:33:14.722 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=07d37e6532d51b0863b6dfc3b8fb4e5dd587603161e9bef7
[I 10:33:14.722 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 10:33:14.738 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=07d37e6532d51b0863b6dfc3b8fb4e5dd587603161e9bef7
[I 10:33:15.012 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[E 10:33:31.275 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /conda/environments?_=1514782996335 (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/conda/environments?_=1514782996335', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36', 'X-Xsrftoken': '2|a7a5484a|d274adf87c4fe4131166ce58d7db4f5c|1514782478', 'Cookie': 'username-localhost-8889="2|1:0|10:1513318792|23:username-localhost-8889|44:ZDRhMWE2OTUxZTc2NGIzZmFiMjE2MjJjYWY3NTA3MDE=|ea230045997be87aaeea2a8776453ec440c302387453009fbb6a4e9fa92ce22c"; _xsrf=2|a7a5484a|d274adf87c4fe4131166ce58d7db4f5c|1514782478; username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1514782995|23:username-localhost-8888|44:YjgxZjc4YzY2MzFiNDhjMmE0MDg4YjNhZDYwNTE3ZDE=|22d9d3588d7327fe7d6b3e526a67977a538e1fe42afbaed04d6cb2a1eed3a711"', 'Host': 'localhost:8888', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01', 'Referer': 'http://localhost:8888/tree', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Save-Data': 'on', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1509, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 2897, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 602, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\site-packages\nb_conda\handlers.py", line 51, in get
        self.finish(json.dumps(self.env_manager.list_envs()))
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\site-packages\nb_conda\envmanager.py", line 67, in list_envs
        info = self.clean_conda_json(self._execute('conda info --json'))
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\site-packages\nb_conda\envmanager.py", line 53, in _execute
        output = check_output(cmdline)
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\subprocess.py", line 316, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\subprocess.py", line 383, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[W 10:33:31.303 NotebookApp] Unhandled error
[E 10:33:31.305 NotebookApp] {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36",
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|a7a5484a|d274adf87c4fe4131166ce58d7db4f5c|1514782478",
      "Cookie": "username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1513318792|23:username-localhost-8889|44:ZDRhMWE2OTUxZTc2NGIzZmFiMjE2MjJjYWY3NTA3MDE=|ea230045997be87aaeea2a8776453ec440c302387453009fbb6a4e9fa92ce22c\"; _xsrf=2|a7a5484a|d274adf87c4fe4131166ce58d7db4f5c|1514782478; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1514782995|23:username-localhost-8888|44:YjgxZjc4YzY2MzFiNDhjMmE0MDg4YjNhZDYwNTE3ZDE=|22d9d3588d7327fe7d6b3e526a67977a538e1fe42afbaed04d6cb2a1eed3a711\"",
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/tree",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "Save-Data": "on",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Connection": "keep-alive"
    }
[E 10:33:31.307 NotebookApp] 500 GET /conda/environments?_=1514782996335 (::1) 49.03ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[E 10:33:31.327 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /conda/packages/available?_=1514782996336 (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/conda/packages/available?_=1514782996336', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36', 'X-Xsrftoken': '2|a7a5484a|d274adf87c4fe4131166ce58d7db4f5c|1514782478', 'Cookie': 'username-localhost-8889="2|1:0|10:1513318792|23:username-localhost-8889|44:ZDRhMWE2OTUxZTc2NGIzZmFiMjE2MjJjYWY3NTA3MDE=|ea230045997be87aaeea2a8776453ec440c302387453009fbb6a4e9fa92ce22c"; _xsrf=2|a7a5484a|d274adf87c4fe4131166ce58d7db4f5c|1514782478; username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1514782995|23:username-localhost-8888|44:YjgxZjc4YzY2MzFiNDhjMmE0MDg4YjNhZDYwNTE3ZDE=|22d9d3588d7327fe7d6b3e526a67977a538e1fe42afbaed04d6cb2a1eed3a711"', 'Host': 'localhost:8888', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01', 'Referer': 'http://localhost:8888/tree', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Save-Data': 'on', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1509, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 2897, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 602, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\site-packages\nb_conda\handlers.py", line 230, in get
        data = searcher.list_available(self)
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\site-packages\nb_conda\handlers.py", line 213, in list_available
        bufsize=4096)
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\Users\Uname\Anaconda3\envs\crawl\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[W 10:33:31.333 NotebookApp] Unhandled error
[E 10:33:31.335 NotebookApp] {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36",
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|a7a5484a|d274adf87c4fe4131166ce58d7db4f5c|1514782478",
      "Cookie": "username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1513318792|23:username-localhost-8889|44:ZDRhMWE2OTUxZTc2NGIzZmFiMjE2MjJjYWY3NTA3MDE=|ea230045997be87aaeea2a8776453ec440c302387453009fbb6a4e9fa92ce22c\"; _xsrf=2|a7a5484a|d274adf87c4fe4131166ce58d7db4f5c|1514782478; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1514782995|23:username-localhost-8888|44:YjgxZjc4YzY2MzFiNDhjMmE0MDg4YjNhZDYwNTE3ZDE=|22d9d3588d7327fe7d6b3e526a67977a538e1fe42afbaed04d6cb2a1eed3a711\"",
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/tree",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "Save-Data": "on",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Connection": "keep-alive"
    }
[E 10:33:31.337 NotebookApp] 500 GET /conda/packages/available?_=1514782996336 (::1) 25.02ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[E 10:35:15.168 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] couldn't call conda:
    [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[I 10:35:22.106 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[W 10:35:24.851 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20180101103312 (::1) 46.03ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python3
[I 10:35:25.520 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 5e64f08c-579a-4557-9890-db8ac8afca87
[I 10:35:29.604 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 5e64f08c-579a-4557-9890-db8ac8afca87
[I 10:37:25.199 NotebookApp] Saving file at /TFGamesSite.ipynb
[I 10:39:26.005 NotebookApp] Saving file at /TFGamesSite.ipynb
```

Comment: Could you update the question with the output of `conda info` and `conda list -ec` ?